# Rotation of image manually in matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, computer-vision, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate the image manually using the following code.

```
clc;
m1 = imread('owl','pgm'); % a simple gray scale image of order 260 X 200
newImg = zeros(500,500);
newImg = int16(newImg);
rotationMatrix45 = [cos((pi/4)) -sin((pi/4)); sin((pi/4)) cos((pi/4))];

for x = 1:size(m1,1)
    for y = 1:size(m1,2)
        point =[x;y] ;
        product = rotationMatrix45 * point;
        product = int16(product);
        newx =product(1,1);
        newy=product(2,1);
        newImg(newx,newy) = m1(x,y);
    end
end
imshow(newImg);
```

Simply I am iterating through every pixel of image `m1`, multiplying m1(x,y) with rotation matrix, I get `x',y'`, and storing the value of `m1(x,y)` in to `newImg(x',y')' **BUT** it is giving the following error

```
??? Attempted to access newImg(0,1); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in ==> at 18
        newImg(newx,newy) = m1(x,y);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the rotated image will get negative (or zero) `newx` and `newy` values since the corners will rotate out of the original image coordinates. You can't assign a value to `newImg` if `newx` or `newy` is nonpositive; those aren't valid matrix indices. One solution would be to check for this situation and skip such pixels (with [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/continue.html))

Another solution would be to enlarge the newImg sufficiently, but that will require a slightly more complicated transformation.

This is assuming that you can't just use [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) because this is homework?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, the answer maybe not : `Matlab arrays` are indexed from one to N (whereas in many programming langages it's from 0 to (N-1) ).

Try `newImg( max( min(1,newX), m1.size() ) , max( min(1,newY), m1.size() ) )` maybe (I don't have Matlab at  work so I can tell if it's gonna work), but the resulting image will be croped.

Comment: That will put all of the pixels falling outside the image frame at the edge of the new image. I think that will look rather funny and I can't imagine that's the desired result.

Comment: oh, you're right. In that case I think he has to go with egdes detection : http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/rotate.htm

Answer (score 0):

this is an old post so I guess it wont help the OP but as I was helped by his attempt I post here my corrected code.
basically some freedom in the implementation regarding to how you deal with unassigned pixels as well as wether you wish to keep the original size of the pic - which will force you to crop areas falling "outside" of it.
the following function rotates the image around its center, leaves unassigned pixels as "burned" and crops the edges.

```
function [h] = rot(A,ang)
rotMat = [cos((pi.*ang/180)) sin((pi.*ang/180)); -sin((pi.*ang/180)) cos((pi.*ang/180))];
centerW = round(size(A,1)/2);
centerH = round(size(A,2)/2);
h=255.* uint8(ones(size(A)));
for x = 1:size(A,1)
    for y = 1:size(A,2)
        point =[x-centerW;y-centerH] ;
        product = rotMat * point;
        product = int16(product);
        newx =product(1,1);
        newy=product(2,1);
            if newx+centerW<=size(A,1)&& newx+centerW > 0 && newy+centerH<=size(A,2)&& newy+centerH > 0 
            h(newx+centerW,newy+centerH) = A(x,y);
            end
    end
end
```